# Why do I keep getting Recovered files in my trash after restarting?

Tags: trash, restart

Whenever I restart my MacBook Pro running OS X 10.6.8, I see a `Recovered files` folder in the trash—most recent example shown below. This is after a regular restart and not after a crash.

Any ideas why this keeps happening?

I'm not sure if this happens on every restart or just regularly. I'll have to investigate more to determine that.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Any file that isn't closed when the program terminates (or the mac crashes or is rebooted) gets flagged as a recovered file.

Usually these are temporary files and never intended by the program to be seen by you. Here are some links from Apple on this behavior:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/PH7225
- http://support.apple.com/kb/PH4205

It is only a problem if you lose work or feel the program should be exiting cleanly and not crashing. Have you looked into the console app to see if the programs are crashing or it's just a matter of shutting things down before the apps have a chance to clean up and quit in an orderly fashion.

Comment: Prior to restarting my MBP, I exited all applications. They appeared to exit cleanly (i.e., they weren't frozen or not responding).

Comment: Hmm - that really should clean them out. Have you tried a safe boot (or single user mode to run fsck by hand before anything mounts) I would expect other shenanigans if the file system were having errors - but it's worth a shot...

Comment: @bmike Your link is broken - do you remember what it was to try to search for a new URL?

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem since I installed Microsoft 2011 for Mac on my system, overtime when I shut down my mac and come back to use it there are recovered files in my trash can. The way I fixed it was by going in the Microsoft word and goto the preference setting/personal settings/feedback it will open a pane for the customer experience improvement program, if you have checked yes you will need to  check no and then click on ok for it to change.

The next step I had to do was open finder goto devices and click the on with you username in the window you will need to click on Macintosh HD / Library / Application support / Microsoft / MERP 2.0 you will look for Microsoft error reporting click on it and on the top bar in the upper left hand conner you will see Microsoft error reporting , click on it and goto preferences a small window will open  and you will see enable error Reporting uncheck that if has been checked close all the window panes out and restart you OS.  Your trash bin should not have and recovered files that were produced by the Microsoft Office 2011 program.

I have not had any issues since doing this over two weeks ago and do not keep having the constant annoyance of emptying the trash bin all the time, I hope this helps .